# How to generalize a HashMap passed to a function with different types of keys?

Tags: rust, hashmap, parameter-passing, generalization

I have a `hm1: HashMap<K, V>` where `K` is a tuple `(k1, 2, k3)` and `V` is a tuple of 10 elements like `(v1, v2, v3, /* ... */ v10)`.

I have a function which acts on that `HashMap`, so I pass it as a parameter:

```
fn do_something(hm1: HashMap<(&i64, &i64, &Option<i64>), (&i64, &i64, /* ... */ &i64)>) -> () {
    //Access k1, k2, k3 and v1 .. v10 and do something with it
}
```

I have a second `HashMap` `hm2` where the only difference is an additional key element. `hm2: HashMap<K, V>` where `K` is a tuple `(k1, k2, k3, k4)` and `V` is again a tuple of 10 elements `(v1, v2, v3, /* ... */ v10)`.

I would want to avoid copy pasting the same `do_something()` function with an adapted signature, because the logic inside is nearly the same. The difference is just that I have an additional `k4` element in the tuple which I'd also access then if I have `hm2`.

Is there a way to generalize the `HashMap<K, V>` parameter so I could pass both `HashMap`s and act on them without duplicating my function?

Comment: I'd use a trait that I'd implement for both the tuples.

Comment: This can be start point https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3cdd6fa9467b2ecfa636e1c8e9897c45

Comment: @Đorđe Zeljić thanks, I think I got it with help of your code! I am implementing methods in the trait to get to the tuple elems, otherwise I don't know how to get them? I hope that's the way to go? Like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9797cbce7faea4eca26b58ce1b15b27e

Comment: @ToniKanoni yes, that was the idea

Comment: @ToniKanoni Are you sure you need all those references? It will be much simpler if you used `i64` and `Option<i64>` instead of `&i64` and `Option<&i64>`.

Comment: @PeterHall Yes, I have no influence on the inputs, they're all refs

Answer (score 0):

> I would want to avoid copy pasting the same `do_something()` function with an adapted signature, because the logic inside is nearly the same.

Copying nearly identical code for different types is what Rust generics are designed for! If the values are the same type in both cases, and only the keys are different, you can abstract over the keys:

```
type Value<'a> = (&'a i64, &'a i64, /* ... */ &'a i64);

fn do_something<K>(hash_map: HashMap<K, Value<'_>>) {
    for value in hash_map.values() {
        // do something with the value
    }
}
```

Given that you know *nothing* about the keys inside the function, you can't do much with them. In particular, you can't destructure them to access individual elements of the key tuples.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this with Generics, what is the second argument "key" here? Inside the the do_something function I need to loop over the complete hashmap (for_each(|(k, v)| ... ) and use all the values. I did it now like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23e4213a0c758408265b22b1492c91d8 Could you translate this into your generic solution?

Comment: My mistake. I somehow misread your original code, and thought the function took a key as  an argument. Fixed it now.